# DirectX 12 does not draw to the render target

Tags: directx, rendering, directx-12

I've got a problem with DirectX 12 I cannot figure out by myself. I wrote a small program that should render a triangle onto the screen.
When I executed the application, however, there was no triangle visible. So I launched NVidia's nsight debugger. The weird thing is that the triangle has been drawn to the depth-stencil buffer but not to the back buffer.

[image]

If you need any code snippets please write it in the comments and I will post it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not give a lot of details to work on, but if your depth buffer got updated, my first guess would be to look at the color write mask.

In `D3D12_RENDER_TARGET_BLEND_DESC`, you have a member named `RenderTargetWriteMask`, it has to be set to `D3D12_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALL`.